# adding set of specific range values in list box in respective columns

Tags: vba, excel

I'm displaying set of range values in two list boxes using VBA form. In `listbox1` headers, then per input displaying relevant data in `listbox2` by using the below code:

```
'header
Set rng = sht.Range("A1:I1")

    With ListBox1
        .ColumnCount = 9
        .ColumnWidths = "50;40;30;120;160;120;50;30;30"
        .RowSource = rng.Address
    End With
'dynamic data 
Set rng1 = sht.Range(Cells(st, ukey), Cells(st + en - 1, utim))

With ListBox2
    .ColumnCount = 9
    .ColumnWidths = "50;40;30;120;160;120;50;30;30"
    .RowSource = rng1.Address
End With
```

How can I add the header and data in one listbox after the heading?

Also how can I add column 10 to 15 in the listbox from another set of ranges?

Answer (score 2):

How to add the header and data in one listbox after the heading?

Unite the two ranges, representing the header and the values like this

```
Set rng = Union(rng, rng1)
.RowSource = rng.Address
```

This is some small sample that works, combining both ranges into one listbox:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Activate()

    Dim rng         As Range
    Dim rngTitle    As Range

    Set rng = Range("D2:L3")
    Set rngTitle = Range("D1:L1")

    Set rng = Union(rng, rngTitle)

    With ListBox1
        .ColumnCount = 9
        .ColumnWidths = "50;40;30;120;160;120;50;30;30"
        .RowSource = rng.Address
    End With

End Sub
```

This is what I get:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help :) I'm getting blank Listbox while trying the above code :(

Comment: @Linga - this is a bit strange, probably you are missing something. Take a look at the updated answer it works quite ok for me.

Comment: I'm checking please wait

Comment: Any specific properties to be enabled?

Comment: @Linga - nope. Just an empty userform with a `ListBox1` in it. And some data in the activesheet in range `"D1:L3"`.

Comment: Tried it Vityata not working if i use UNION :( I'm using 2010 version is that the reason?

Comment: @Linga - shound not be. Are you sure that you have copied and paste the exact code from the answer? Into a userform? Then clicked F5 and clicked on the UserForm and nothing happened? I have changed the event to `_Activate` just to avoid the clicking.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167345/discussion-between-linga-and-vityata).

Answer (score 0):

I merged the ranges by using UNION as mentioned above by Vityata and moved them to a temp workbook and displayed by using the below code :)

```css
Set rngt1 = sht.Range("A1:I1")
Set rngt2 = sht.Range("X1:AE1")
Set rngt3 = sht.Range("AI1")

Set rngd1 = sht.Range(Cells(st, ukey), Cells(st + en - 1, utim))
Set rngd2 = sht.Range(Cells(st, ccat), Cells(st + en - 1, etag))
Set rngd3 = sht.Range(Cells(st, comt), Cells(st + en - 1, comt))

Set rngt = Union(rngt2, rngt1)
Set rngt = Union(rngt3, rngt)
Set rngd = Union(rngd2, rngd1)
Set rngd = Union(rngd3, rngd)

Workbooks.Add
rngt.Copy ActiveSheet.Range("A1")
rngd.Copy ActiveSheet.Range("A2")

Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(en + 1, 18))
  

    With ListBox2
        .ColumnCount = 18
        .RowSource = rng.Address
        .ColumnHeads = True
    End With
```

Thank you Vityata for the help :)